# Can one get clear ice crystals from a dirty suspension?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, freezing

Euteictic freeze crystallization is a method where an electrolytic solution is cooled and separated into a stream of (relativly) clean, pure ice and a salty brine. I know anectdotally of wine concentrates that where made similiar. Now I wonder wether a suspension of solids can be separated in a similiar way, and if so under what circumstances, and if not, why.

Some half baked thoughts of mine:

- Anecdotally, if I put soup into the the freezer, no easily visible separation occurs.
- With comparativly large suspended particles, a growing ice crystal may not be able to 'push' particles away and encapsulate them instead.
- With salty solutions, the brine is denser than the water or ice and separates by gravity - while in my soup, er suspension, some solids will settle at the top with the ice and become frozen in it.
- The whole thing my simply be a matter of time, with slower freezing allowing for cleaner crystals

Comment: Another relevant thought: if the solid particles act as nucleation sites then each will start out embedded in its own ice crystal and they won't get separated at all.

Comment: yeat another relevant thought: aa suspended particle might be pushed by one large, growing crystal, but could be trapped between several smaller, growing ones.