# How to homegrow large, momocrystalline water ice crystals

Tags: thermodynamics, water, home-experiment, crystals, freezing

This is a follow up to [this question:**Can one get clear ice crystals from a dirty suspension?**](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64565/can-one-get-clear-ice-crystals-from-a-dirty-suspension).

How could one grow a large - meaning visible with the naked eye - water ice crstal with common household tools and substances or little exotic/rare equipment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say I know any that do it. A small refrigerator modified with clear panels and post who tip acts as the seed-point for nucleation - this is the basic concept of the lab setup a for ice crystal growth.

I think your objectives need to be stated better. "Large" could be an imaginative thing wherein a real implementation will demand you grow on a substrate. This then creates its own problems regarding purity of the crystal and morphology.

I'm on mobile, so pardon the lack of references.

Comment: Crystal growth does not like vibration, in general - (large crystals even more so) and refridgerators typically vibrate. Could be worth to decouple mechanically from the refridgerator wall, like putting something soft under the crystal setup.